# LaTex Problem regarding cellcolor with @\hspace*{3ex}

Tags: tables

I have following problem with my table I cannot fix. I want a table with two columns that have lists in it with bulletpoints. However due to the command `@{\hspace*{3ex}` does also the cell color start after `3ex` which is not what I want.I tried to move it back with `\hspace*{-3ex}` but that only affects the text. Can someone help me with that?

My `\tabitem` command looks as following:

```
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}     
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}     
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]    
\caption{XYZ}    
\label{RisikenChancen}

\begin{tabular}{{|@{\hspace*{3ex}} L{6,7cm}|@{\hspace*{3ex}} L{6,7cm}|}}   
\hline    
\hspace*{-3ex} \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  \textbf{Risiken von Industrie 4.0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} \textbf{Chancen von Industrie 4.0} \\     
\hline    
\tabitem Dequalifizierung und Vertiefung von Arbeitsteilung     
\par \tabitem Automatisierung, insbes. Verlust einfacher Arbeitspl\"atze    
&     
\tabitem Voraussetzung f\"ur eine humanorientierte Arbeitsgestaltung     
\par \tabitem Erweiterung des Aufgabenspektrums und Erh\"ohung von Qualifikationen \\    
\tabularnewline    
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the compilable code, not just fragments only!

Comment: What is the `L` columnn type?

Comment: I just updated the compilable version, L is also defined.

Comment: Also make sure this compiles, there is no `colour` or `tabular` packages. Use `xcolor` for the first, and remove the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a simpler solution. It goes through defining a new column type, which includes entering in a convenient `itemize` environment on entering a cell, and leaving `itemize` on leaving the cell. Of course column heads have to be defined as \multicolumn s, which is done with a `\myhead` command, which accepts one optional argument, the alignment of the head (`c` by default). The content of \myhead is automatically typed in boldface.

The new column type  exists in two variants: `I`, which is a `>{…}p{some width}<{…}`, and  `J`, which is a  `>{…}X<{…}`, for use with `tabularx, so that the table never overflows into the margin.

Finally, I took the liberty to change the column heads colour to a nicer grey – at least for my taste.

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{babel}%
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\usepackage{enumitem, ragged2e} %
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse} %
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\myhead{O{c}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\bfseries#2}}

\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\itemize[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, before={\vspace*{-0.35\baselineskip}}, after={\vspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}}]}p{#1}<{\enditemize}}

\newcolumntype{J}{>{\arraybackslash\itemize[nosep, leftmargin=*, before={\vspace*{-0.35\baselineskip}}, after={\vspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}}]}X<{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \captionsetup{font=bf, singlelinecheck=false}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{0.6ex}
  \caption{XYZ}

  \label{RisikenChancen}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| J !{|} J !{|}}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Lavender!80!lightgray} %
    \myhead[|c|]{Risiken von Industrie 4.0} & \myhead[c|]{Chancen von Industrie 4.0} \\
    \hline
    \item Dequalifizierung und Vertiefung von Arbeitsteilung
    \item Automatisierung, insbes. Verlust einfacher Arbeitsplätze
                                            &
    \item Voraussetzung für eine humanorientierte Arbeitsgestaltung
    \item Erweiterung des Aufgabenspektrums und Erhöhung von Qualifikationen \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{| I{6.7cm}|I{6.7cm}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Lavender!80!lightgray} %
    \myhead[|c|]{Risiken von Industrie 4.0} & \myhead[c|]{Chancen von Industrie 4.0} \\
    \hline
    \item Dequalifizierung und Vertiefung von Arbeitsteilung
    \item Automatisierung, insbes. Verlust einfacher Arbeitsplätze
                                            &
    \item Voraussetzung für eine humanorientierte Arbeitsgestaltung
    \item Erweiterung des Aufgabenspektrums und Erhöhung von Qualifikationen \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, can you elaborate where is used `[1]` in definition of `J` column type? For `I` is clear, where, but for `J` I cant figured out.

Comment: @Zarko: I copy-pasted the definition of `I` and forgot to remove it. As it had no effect on compilation, I didn't notice. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Bernard, my tests shows difference in obtained result (vertical line disappear, instead it shows up long dash), if this option is present or not. SO, there is some magic in this option or in definition of this column type (I'm very interested for it).

Comment: I figured out what cause the problem: omitting of this option you also need to change `!{|}` to `|` :-)

Comment: You're right , I also have a problem with vertical lines for `J`, and I can't explain it. A workaround  consists in replacing the `|` column separators with `!{|}`.

Comment: one more question (maybe I should ask as separate question), is possible to change width of `J` column type, or it is frozen by `\itemize`?

Comment: @Zarko: width of what?

Comment: I will ask new question

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The table looks great now, especially with the new grey. It's my very first work in LaTex so I am very ignorant of all the options and the programming!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Bernard solution, very similar but without `enumitem` and `xparse` and with added `calc` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc,tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{J}{>{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
    \arraybackslash%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}%
            {\widthof{\labelitemi}+\labelsep}% less list indent
    \itemize%
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt + 10pt}% for ragged right
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
                        }%
    X<{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\enditemize\endminipage}%
                    }
\makeatother
\newcommand\myhead[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}   

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \captionsetup{font=bf, singlelinecheck=false}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \caption{XYZ}

  \label{RisikenChancen}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| J | J |}
    \hline
\rowcolor{Lavender!80!lightgray} %
\myhead{|c|}{Risiken von Industrie 4.0} 
    &   \myhead{c|}{Chancen von Industrie 4.0}              \\
    \hline
\item Dequalifizierung und Vertiefung von Arbeitsteilung
\item Automatisierung, insbes. Verlust einfacher Arbeitsplätze
    &   \item Voraussetzung für eine humanorientierte Arbeitsgestaltung
        \item Erweiterung des Aufgabenspektrums und Erhöhung von Qualifikationen \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]