# Is possible to change width of column defined on `X` column type with integrated itemize environment?

Tags: itemize, tabularx, enumitem, columns

This is following on question to nice Bernard answer on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327346/latex-problem-regarding-cellcolor-with-hspace3ex)
where as solution he proposed new column type:

```
\newcolumntype{J}{>{\arraybackslash
                    \itemize[nosep, leftmargin=*,
                             before={\vspace*{-0.35\baselineskip}}, 
                             after={\vspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}}
                                ]
                       }X<{\enditemize}}
```

example of it use is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{enumitem} %
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{J}[1]{>{\arraybackslash
                       \itemize[nosep, leftmargin=*,
                                before={\vspace*{-0.35\baselineskip}},  
                                after={\vspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}}
                                ]
                       }X<{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\setlength\hsize{0.25\hsize}}J | 
                               >{\setlength\hsize{0.75\hsize}}J |}
    \hline
\item Dequalifizierung und Vertiefung von Arbeitsteilung
\item Automatisierung, insbes. Verlust einfacher Arbeitsplätze
    &    \item Voraussetzung für eine humanorientierte Arbeitsgestaltung
         \item Erweiterung des Aufgabenspektrums und Erhöhung von Qualifikationen \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which gives unexpected result:

[image]

Width of both columns are the same, but I expect that they would be in ratio 1:3. What prevent to so defined column type that it not obey

```
>{\setlength\hsize{0.5\hsize}}X
```

as this is for example in case of

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

and use for example as:

```
>{\setlength\hsize{0.5\hsize}}L
```

So far my attempt to solve this problem fails, column width persist to stay as it is determined (i suppose) by `tabularx` internals, i.e. with equal width. So I wonder, what in definition of `J` column type had to be changed that standard way to change of `X` columns will work for `J` columns too.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I sorted out some solution, but not on the way as I like to have. With out of use `enumitem` package I'm able to change the width of `J` column type, however not on standard way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%    
\newcolumntype{J}[1]{
    >{\setlength\hsize{#1\hsize}    % <-- added
    \minipage[t]{\hsize+2\tabcolsep}% <-- added
    \arraybackslash%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}%
            {\widthof{\labelitemi}+\labelsep}% less list indent
    \itemize%
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt + 10pt}% for ragged right
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
        \setlength\labelsep{1ex}%
        \setlength{\listparindent}{3em}
    }X<{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\enditemize\endminipage
        }%
                    }
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
table with column type \verb+J+:\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| J{0.25} | J{0.75} |}
    \hline
\item   short tex in the first column
    &   \item   long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long tex in the second column  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}

table with column type \verb+L+:\\
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\setlength\hsize{0.25\hsize}}L |
                                  >{\setlength\hsize{0.75\hsize}}L |}
    \hline
short tex in the first column
    &   long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long tex in the second column  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Drawbacks of this solution:

- No standard way to determine ration of columns in `tabularx`.
- The ratio coefficients at `\hsize` had to be smaller than one and their sum should be one (otherwise arise discrepancy between column width and `\hline` width.

So I still looking for better solution.